# Can a Telegram bot return multiple messages on a single message trigger?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, telegram, telegram-bot

When an user triggers my bot, I want to post some text in multiple chat. Maybe the the chat in which he triggered the bot and another channel or so...

```
res.status(200).send({
    method: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id,
    text: `Some random text . . .`,
    parse_mode: 'HTML'
})
```

This is something used to return single message.

I want to return multiple so I tried something like:

```
return [
    res.status(200).send({
        method: 'sendMessage',
        chat_id: firstChatId,
        text: `Some more random text`,
        parse_mode: 'HTML'
    }),
    res.status(200).send({
        method: 'sendMessage',
        chat_id: secondChatId,
        text: `Random text forever`,
        parse_mode: 'HTML'
    })
]
```

But only the first one got executed. I looked over the internet and found somewhere that only 1 message could be replied.
Is there any workaround for this? Creating another bot to just post the text in another chat won't be ideal way, especially because you can create only 20 bots.

Comment: you need to call https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

Comment: @AlanBirtles that's what I am using right now but can you say how do I add multiple `chat_id` to return message to multiple chats?

Comment: You need to call the api rather than just sending a response

Comment: @AlanBirtles the code mentioned in my question gets triggered by https req in firebase like this `export const botFn = functions.https.onRequest(bot)`